# GAM model error - missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, model, gam

I'm trying to create a GAM model using environmental variables and mean abundance data.

the data im using is:[image]

and the code I'm using to create the model is so:

```
imod2 <- gam(mean ~  s(BO_chlomean, bs="cr"), data = envgroup2, family = poisson, method="REML", na.action = na.fail, select=T)
```

(ideally I want to add the other 2 variables but one thing at a time.)

however when I run the code I get:

```
Error in if (abs(old.score - score) > score.scale * conv.tol) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I also get 50 or more warnings, consisting of:

```
1: In dpois(y, y, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 0.200000
```

i'm very new to R and finding to hard to understand. any help to sort this issue would be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking `gam()` to fit a model assuming an **integer** response and passing it a real-valued (decimal) variable.

If you have replicate counts and averaged them to get the `mean` variable, then don't do the averaging. Include all rows of data and deal with the clustering by subject with a random effect term.

If you got `mean` by scaling by an effort variable, you should fit the model with the original count/integer values and add `offset(log(effort_var))` to the formula where `effort_var` is the variable you divided the original response by to get `mean`.